# Kotlin: lambda run alternative scenario

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have userDto, contains `programs`, which contains `actual` field. Actual program can be only one. I need to get it. Than, I run this:

```
userDto.programs.sortedBy { it.created }.findLast { it.actual }?
```

Okay, but I want to foresee case, when `findLast` returns null, & throw exception. Please, advice, how to do it?

UPD:

```
ProgramType.valueOf(userDto.programs
                                .sortedBy { it.created }
                                .findLast { it.actual }
                        //check here
                        !!.programType!!).percentage
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close actually :)! What you could do is:

```
userDto.programs.sortedBy { it.created }.findLast { it.actual } ?: throw RuntimeException()
```

Or if you're trying to actually avoid throwing an error(couldn't really tell with the way question is asked), you could just do an error check like this:

```
userDto.programs.sortedBy { it.created }.findLast { it.actual }?.let{
//rest of your code goes here
}
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: but if I want to continue to process expression result after check, like in updfated example?